# Expanding formulas in Excel via python (Openpyxl)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I've been trying to write an automation to my excel file and besides that to learn some python. I'm using openpyxl. I encountered a problem when I wanted to expand formula from one cell to another in multiple rows and colums.

For example
[We've got here 4 rows of numbers in 3 columns. In cells D2,E2,F2,G2 I have some basic formulas Sum "=A2+B2+C2, Multiply "=A2*B2*C2, divide "=A2/B2/C2, average "=AVERAGE(A2:C2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5I0A.png)

I've tried many possibilities, rewriting code multiple times and still I cant get resolution. Documentation for openpyxl is very poor and doesn't answer my question.

Something I tried recently:
`ws1` is the name of the worksheet

```
for row in ws1.iter_cols(min_col= 4, min_row = 2, max_row = ws1.max_row, max_col = ws1.max_column):
    formula = row[0].value
    for cell in row:
        cell = row[0]
        cell_coordinate = cell.coordinate 
        str(cell_coordinate)
        cell.value = Translator(formula,origin = cell_coordinate ).translate_formula()
```

I know it's probably wrong but I don't know how to fix it.

Appreciate for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you're using current cell's [`coordinate`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html#openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell.coordinate) as the origin of the [`Translator`](https://ssopenpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5.2/openpyxl.formula.translate.html#openpyxl.formula.translate.Translator).

You can fix it this way :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.formula.translate import Translator

wb = load_workbook("file.xlsx")
ws = wb.active # or wb["SheetName"]

SR, SC = 2, 4 # which is D2

d = {
    "sum": ("=SUM(A2:C2)", "D2"),
    "multiply": ("=PRODUCT(A2:C2)", "E2"),
    "divide": ("=A2/B2/C2", "F2"),
    "average": ("=AVERAGE(A2:C2)", "G2")
}

for col, agg in zip(ws.iter_cols(min_row=SR, min_col=SC), d):
    for idx, cell in enumerate(col):
        cell.value = Translator(
            *d.get(agg)
        ).translate_formula(cell.coordinate)

wb.save("file.xlsx") # this is an inplace modification
```

Output (*file.xlsx*) :

[image]

Comment: **NB** : The formatting in the spreadsheet above is for clarify purposes (black for `I` and green for `O`).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, but I have yet another problem:
How do I apply a path to different sheet to this part:
d = {
    "sum": ("=SUM(A2:C2)", "D2"),
    "multiply": ("=PRODUCT(A2:C2)", "E2"),
    "divide": ("=A2/B2/C2", "F2"),
    "average": ("=AVERAGE(A2:C2)", "G2")
}

For example I need to use such line:
"STID":  ("=VLOOKUP(BQ2,'Mapping'!$V:$Y,4,FALSE)", "BQ2"),
But it says that it's invalid syntax. How do I fix the formatting?